# Zen theme not writing source maps

Tags: theming

I have made a subtheme of zen and started making some changes to it's SASS files.
However now I have some layouts that aren't working as I expected, so I went to the chrome devtools, but that only tells me what CSS file the particular thing is in.

What I want is what SASS file it is in. Now, when I read the config.rb file it says it has some support for FireSass, but that plugin has been removed by the author, so no luck there.

I do have the environment set to :development and the firesass = true, therefore the sass_options :debug_info => true.

So I go to the root in the theme file /sites/all/themes/mytheme and run compass watch, but there are never any source maps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2295227 addresses your question.

Though haven't tried it myself, but the current dev-version of [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) should contain the 'fix' (i.e., using FireCompass instead of FireSass) to debug SASS-code in an easy way.

Comment: That just is a replacement for FireSass, which is useful but doesn't solve the problem I was having in te first place. Not generating source maps ;)

Comment: @Noë, ok sorry, misunderstood your question.. Thought you were trying to debug your SASS with FireSass.

Answer (score 0):

I had to give the sass_options en extra element { :sourcemaps => true } this solves the problem. A demo about how to do just that can be found here: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/zen/tree/STARTERKIT/config.rb?id=8ffd0ac18b51b7a01f2c6019882adb1cb044b340

Don't know why this isn't in Zen 5.5 though.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Compass, best way is to just update your ruby gems, worked for me.

```
gem update
```